# Page not working properly after pushing it in subscribe Firebase.onNotificationOpen Ionic 2

Tags: html, typescript, firebase, ionic2, ionic3

I have an Ionic 2 app which uses Firebase to send notifications to users. In the app.component.ts file I have a _setupFirebase function in which I subscribe to 
Firebase.onNotificationOpen.

```
private _setupFirebase() {
    //if I push the page here it works properly
    this.nav.push(MyPage);
    Firebase.onNotificationOpen()
        .subscribe(data => {
            //if I push the page here it doesn't work
            this.nav.push(MyPage);
    });
}
```

The problem is that I need the data obtained in the onNotificationOpen method to choose which page to open depending on the notification and send some data through to that page.
The page I'm pushing has a form that has a few checkboxes. If I push that page in the subscription of onNotificationOpen, like on line 7 of the code, when I click on a checkbox the value changes but the view doesn't get updated.

Comment: So you just want to send data to the page?

Comment: The data tells me what kind of notification it is so I know what page to push. And there are also some values in the data that I need to send to the page.